# Getting bike lane length with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, line, length

I am trying to get bike lane lengths from [the following data set](https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Transportation/Bicycle-Routes/7vsa-caz7).

To do so I have tried using the add geometry attribute from the processing toolbox.

I have tried both calculate using Layer CRS and Ellipsoidal and gotten similar untrue results.

For instance, in running this it says one bike lane segment is only `.08 km` when it should be `1.18 km`.

Any guesses for how to fix this (accuracy)?

Comment: If you are downloading the _Original_ Dataset, the units from the layer CRS are feets. About your ellipsoid, what are the units that you are using?

Comment: Also, there is no feature geometry that has a length between 1.0 and 1.3 km, why do you say that an entity should have that length (1.18km)? I think you would have no problem in obtaining the ellipsoidal distance from a layer in geodetic coordinates if you had the ellipsoid of the project well configured. Perhaps there is a sum of deconfiguration of the ellipsoid of the project added to that you are working in a layer in geodetic coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

The Data you downloaded is in the `EPSG:4326` (WGS 84 - Geographic) reference system, which means data are internally saved in a "latitude,longitude" format.

To calculate the correct length of features, you need to use a projected CRS, like UTM.

Since your data is in New York, you will want to use UTM zone `18N` (`EPSG:32618`):

[image]

### Method 1 (just add the projected length)

Set the Project CRS to `UTM 18N`:

[image]

Then use the `Add geometry attribute`, but selecting the `Project CRS` option:

[image]

### Method 2 (reprojection of the layer)

[re-project the layer](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/vector_analysis/reproject_transform.html#moderate-fa-saving-a-dataset-to-another-crs) into a projected CRS (like UTM).

[image]

then:

[image]

Finally, calculate the lengths using `Add geometry attribute` in its default configuration.